# Import SQLight database on Excel

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I'm trying to import data from a SQLight database to EXCEL with vba and here is my code :

```vb
Sub Importer_Contrat()
    Dim conn As Object, rst As Object
    Dim strSQL As String, table_name As String

    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    ' OPEN CONNECTION
    conn.Open "DRIVER=SQLite3 ODBC Driver;Database=" & Chemin_BDD & BDD2 & ";"

    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM " & Contract_Table

    ' OPEN RECORDSET]
    rst.Open strSQL, conn

    ' OUTPUT TO WORKSHEET
    sh_test_sql.Range("test_paste").CopyFromRecordset rst
    rst.Close
End Sub
```

My data data base has only 3 columns (chrono is `Integer`, Nom is `Text` and Date is `Integer`)

The vba works wells when I request an Integer but each time it is asked to import Data from the column Name which is Text and not Integer it doesn't work.

With the code above I just receive the first colum Chrono in Integer.

What is also very strange is that if i use this code :

```vb
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM " & Contract_Table

' OPEN RECORDSET]
rst.Open strSQL, conn

Do While Not rst.EOF
    MsgBox rst(1)
    rst.MoveNext
Loop
```

I can see the Text I want to import but it doesn't work with the recorset. Do you know where the problem is coming from ? I need to paste a big table on my Excel sheet and I've been looking the answer for days now.

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

It seems that, while the data is present in the recordset, the `CopyFromRecordset` method fails to work. As I have used this method quite a lot against other data sources, I would assume that there is an issue with the ODBC driver.

There are many ways to read the data from a recordset. You can loop over it manually, or you can use the `GetRows` method to build a 2-dimensional array. This 2-dimensional array has the *column* as first index and the *row* as second, both dimensions are 0-based.

The following code uses this method and writes the data into a sheet - only that rows and columns are exchanged. I did a test with `Worksheetfunction.Transpose` to change this but got a runtime error `Type mismatch`.

```
Dim myData
myData = rst.GetRows

Dim r As Range
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Set r = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(UBound(x, 1) + 1, UBound(x, 2) + 1))        
    r.Value = x
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer. I also think that there is an issue with the ODBC driver and the function CopyFromRecordset. I have solved my issue with a loop on each value of the sql database and an Array that I paste in my Excel :

```
ReDim Contract_Array(nb_row - 1, Nb_col_DB_Contracts - 1)
For row_runner = 0 To nb_row - 1
    For col_runner = 0 To Nb_col_DB_Contracts - 1 
        Contract_Array(row_runner, col_runner) = rst(col_runner)
    Next col_runner
    rst.MoveNext
Next row_runner

sh_test_sql.Range("A1:G2").Value = Contract_Array
```

Thank you for your help !